The universe has always existed, infinite cycles
"The universe has always existed." And "The universe goes through big bang to big crunch, and back and forth." And "Without history repeating itself."
Is this position viable logically?
Because the idea that the universe does not have a beginning and just cycles without any losses due to entropy as a scientific concept seems identical to religions who have a creator who also doesn't have a beginning and also violates entropy.
They are both unsound positions from the perspective of pure science right? (Not meta-physics)
Is my reasoning here flawed? If so, can someone kindly say how?
Also forgive me, I am not well knowledged in the proper tags here. I believe I am in the right SE site, this is not a physics question it is about the logic behind the question.

Without the history repeating though @MauroALLEGRANZA (I edited it in, thanks for catching that. I meant to add it.

You mean Roger Penrose's Conforming Cyclic Cosmology?

You mean these scenarios are identical aside from the existence of a supernatural entity that passed their laws only to a select chosen ones but you better follow them to the letter, or else…?

@MisterMiyagi I am not engaging in religious debate, that is not the purpose of this website is it? I am asking if the premise is sound, because I think it breaks physics on both sides. Religious or "infinite bang-crunch" both are like "cop outs" aren't they?

As soon as you ask "from the perspective of pure science", you are no longer talking philosophy in the modern sense. You need to ask a physicist.

@DavidGudeman I suspect if I ask them, they will all get upset by using the g word and tell me to go back here. As my question was about the logic of it, and not the physics of it... I assumed philosophy was the proper place.

Maybe I misunderstood your intent. Are we just supposed to assume the truth of your claim about entropy to answer the question? In that case, what good would the answer be since it would be merely speculative?

@Wyrsa Well, you don’t need the g-word to ask the science question, so it is indeed odd to see it with an extra questionable comparison on top. We can model a cyclic universe just fine, we cannot model a religious creator, we certainly can’t model a cyclic universe that is identical to one with a religious creator. The r-word adds a ton of baggage.

"As my question was about the logic of it, and not the physics of it..." This is not clear from the question as is right now, at all. The pure science dabbling with a cyclical universe is physics, as is the pure science dabbling with entropy; the logic of both is physics. Unless of course you are aiming for the g-word, but you also just said you don’t.

I agree with David that this is a question for a physicist, but one thing to consider is that the second law of thermodynamics is a statistical statement that the probability of universe-wide entropy decreasing is extremely low (so low that it's effectively impossible long term). But when you start throwing in infinite time-scales, any event with a finite probability, no matter how small, becomes almost certain to occur.

@Wyrsa here's how I'd phrase it for Physics.SE: "How do "Big Bounce"-style cosmologies get around thermodynamics and entropy? -- There's some theories like Roger Penrose's Conforming Cyclic Cosmpology that posit that the universe is one iteration of an eternal cycle. Putting aside observational evidence, I don't understand conceptually how concepts like these don't violate thermodynamics. How would the entropy "reset"?"

I'm a Christian BUT that should make no difference to the following. Your " ... seems identical to religions who have a creator who also doesn't have a beginning ... " has a problem with "seems". The two are very different, and you'll easily find as much discussion of this on web as you wish. To conflate the two places you at grave risk of making an assumption so you can then feel justified in filing G away without further consideration. Better, if you must do so, is to acknowledge to yourself that that is an area that you have decided to refuse to engage with and label it accordingly.

The question of infinite origination is historically addressed by Kant's Antinomies, where in the  Observations on the 3rd Antimony is stated: "It is ... the true stumbling-stone to philosophy, which meets with unconquerable difficulties in the way of its admitting this kind of unconditioned causality." It confounds reason and has to be left moot.  Kant instead turns his attention to the transcendental unity of apperception as a more tractable foothold in reality.

@ChrisDegnen  A useful comment. It hasn't stopped very many people since attempting to hand wave it away as sensibly physically possible. Two recent famousish exemplars are Stephen Hawkings and Michael Kraus. Both explain in some detail that ex Nihilo creation is scientifically sensible. And both then build their explanations on eternally existant "somethings". "Despite being a Christian :-) " I try very hard indeed to understand all viewpoints as well as I may. It seems inescapable that there is a metaphysical underpinning to our reality. Doesn't have to be 'God' per se.

If Philosophy must relegate issues like this solely to Physics then Philosophy is a very barren discipline indeed. The only physical choices are "always has been" and "ex nihilo".  Both are physically impossible (although that doesn't stop each new generation of hopefuls trying again to rescue "past infinities"). Ex nihilo without a metaphysical foundation is beyond salvation.  Physics & Philosophy are unavoidably mutually entwined here. Neither is permitted to leave the party :-).

@RussellMcMahon I had wondered... Pure philosophy is a very very high level of abstraction to insist on. And my question was about the logic involved... which I admit drags physics into this, but doesn't change that the question was "is this logical or nonsense?" ... Like I could rewrite it into pure logical equations and then pose the question again, but who does that benefit? Surely not the person who has the question...

@RussellMcMahon & Wyrsa. Just to recap Kant's 'logical' objection to eternally existant "somethings" – he simply says an infinite span of time would need to elapse to reach today, but an infinite span of time could never reach completion.

@ChrisDegnen  I think that's similar to the various objections to "past infinities". Future infinities are not the same as we are at this finite point at the start of them :-)

This question actually belongs in the astronomy stax, but If you want the science answer, Yes, that model has been proposed by no less than Roger Penrose, Nobel Prize winner.
In 2011, he wrote a book proposing this idea, a series of big bangs.

this concept seems identical to religions who have a creator who also doesn't have a beginning and also violates entropy.

No, Roger Penrose is the world's expert on entropy since his sidekick Hawking died. The way he formulated it, doesn't violate entropy. Think of the tangent function. It's produced by something smoothly rotating, and yet its value jumps from negative Infinity to positive Infinity discontinuously, all from smooth rotation that doesn't lose any energy.
No, I don't believe it either, but that's what he says. At least, to the extent that I understand it — which I may very well not.
He also fails to explain the beginning of this chain, but I don't hold that against him at all. We're still discovering what's happening, and we don't have the whole picture yet.
So yes, your theory has been seriously proposed by a serious astrophysicist.
I like the idea because it allows you to see momentum in the direction of future time (how Feynman described mass) as angular momentum. But it's way too speculative to believe.

(If you have the time and energy, if you want to dig up what Penrose's solution to entropy are, I'd be grateful. this physics SE doesn't have any answers

Well in high school, I was gonna be a lawyer, because that's the only field where logical arguments matter. But to my horror, I discovered that you have to be able to argue the side of something you don't believe. == I can't do that. == Although, I believe the answer involved the fact that dimensions can play against each other like that when one of them is negative.  That describes time. The imaginary axis becomes the rotational axis. Seeing photons as rotation around an imaginary axis is actually extremely useful. == He was very insightful; I just think he was wrong.

Bouncing cosmologies long precede Penrose's recent suggestion. For a very early idea see Tolman (1931). More explicit models appeared in the late 70s, e.g. Melnikov & Orlov (1979). For review see e.g. Novello & Perez Bergliaffa (2008). Penrose's ego doesn't need any further fluffing, and anyway his is far from the most sensible of these suggestions.

Yo Miss Understands, happy to see you respond. Thanks for the answer. And I agree it seems dubious at best. Wish we could chat about it

@SethK > Bouncing cosmologies long precede Penrose == Yeah, but Penrose didn't see  a bounce. He saw a continuous 4D rotation.  Nothing bounced. Nothing changed direction.

Perhaps not a full answer, but my two cents: if “viable” means “supported by evidence”, then any Big Crunch-expecting stance will require that you explain the current expansion pattern of the Universe. The density of the Universe appears to cosmologists right now to be less-than-critical, so dark energy is in an abstract sense stronger than gravity and gravity can never cause a collapse back to singularity (barring K4-level artificial intervention).
If, however, you’re willing to believe that the Universe could collapse back into a singularity and do another Big Bang, then repeat ad infinitum, then you will eventually find issues with the Poincare recurrence theorem and the like. The observable Universe is finite in extent, and thus contains a finite amount of information; given this, there are a finite number of possible “histories” that could take place between any given Big Bang and Big Crunch, albeit such a large number that it would not be unfair to say that it is, for all human purposes, infinite.

Have you looked at the times involved for the PRT to occur? If any collapse will take place, it will have happened waaaaay before any recurrence issues.

My point is primarily that, given the finity of information content in the Universe, even allowing for collapse (shouldn’t be possible, tmk), there cannot be an infinity of histories that can/will take place.

Penrose's cycles don't involve any collapse. The expansions just get so large that the ends of the cycles become equivalent to their beginnings.

I have not been one to accept that at face value. That theory has always seemed a little far-fetched to me. But ignoring that aspect of it, you still find that the information content of the Universe is finite, so my second point stands.

@controlgroup I see what you mean. I thought you proposed the recurrence between a single Big Bang and a Crunch (which I agree is not a presently supported theory).

@D.Halsey > Penrose's cycles don't involve any collapse. The expansions just get so large that the ends of the cycles become equivalent to their beginning == YES! He called that conformal infinity, as I remember. He squeezed the upper half of the Minkowski space diagram so that all future paths converge to a point. That gave all possible paths in Minkowski space a left and right hand edge. He saw event horzons as the limit as you approach that edge.

@D.Halsey He also said that the interiors of black holes are on the other side of that conformal boundary. He says we can never get there from any world line in spacetime. That contradicts what everybody at stax says, that GR implies you can cross the event horizon. Penrose says you can't, you can only go as far as infinitely close to the horizon. I absolutely agree with that, but I think I'm the only one that does besides Penrose. == ...Unless I'm remembering it wrong or don't understand it, which is almost certainly the case. His math made sense, but the concept was totally bizarro.
